# How to add script tag in jekyll?

Tags: html, ruby, github, jekyll

Jekyll is a simple, blog-aware, static site generator for personal, project, how do i add a script tag in such ruby project.

My index.html looks like this :

```
---
layout: default
---

<div class="home">

  <h1 class="page-heading">Posts</h1>

  <ul class="post-list">
    {% for post in site.posts %}
      <li>
        <span class="post-meta">{{ post.date | date: "%b %-d, %Y" }}</span>

        <h2>
          <a class="post-link" href="{{ post.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
        </h2>
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>

  <p class="rss-subscribe">subscribe <a href="{{ "/feed.xml" | prepend: site.baseurl }}">via RSS</a></p>

</div>
```

the folder structure also consists of files and folders like this : `about.md  _config.yml  css  feed.xml  _includes  index.html  _layouts  _posts  _sass  _site`

i am trying to explore the jekyll platform for static web pages.

Answer (score 28):

**Step 1: Make the Script file.**

Create the script (`.js`) file as normal.

You might want to save in an appropriate folder, for example:

`../assets/js/some-script.js`

You may need to make the `/assets/` folder if you do not have it.

Don't use underscore (`_`) at the front of the folder name and Jekyll will then simply copy that folder and contents into the build at `_site' as a static asset.

**Step 2: Call / reference the script in your html.**

Then just call it as you want it, like:

`...<script src="{{ base.url | prepend: site.url }}/assets/some-script.js"></script>...`.

If you want the script available on every page, put the call in your `default.html` layout file. Every page that uses that default.html layout will then call the script. That layout file can be found at `_layouts/default.html`.

If you just want it on your current page, just call it in your `some-page.md` markdown in the same way.

If you only want to call it when it is live and DON'T want to call it while you are developing - like, for example, a google analytics script - then wrap the call in an if statement like this:

`{% if site.environment == "production" %}<script src="//localhost:35729/livereload.js"></script>{% endif %}`

Hope this helps.

Comment: If I put a script tag in a md file I get in the md file: <script src=assets/about.js></script> So the tag is parsed as a string.

Comment: If you want the script available on every page, then instead of calling  it in _layouts/default.html as suggested above, call it instead in _includes/scripts.html file which is a placeholder for calling various scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your `<script>` tag to the file:

```
_includes/head-custom.html
```

It will be then included on all pages.